# new file monitoring script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i was making a shell script which can "send me email whenever any new file come in particular directory, with new file's name size and timestamp".

following code is doing this job well :

```
#!/bin/bash

monitor_dir=/path/to/dir
email=me@me.com

files=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
IFS=$'\n'

while true
do
  sleep 5s

  newfiles=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
  added=$(comm -13 <(echo "$files") <(echo "$newfiles"))

  [ "$added" != "" ] &&
    find $added -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' |
    mail -s "incoming" "$email"

  files="$newfiles"
done
```

now i want same feature with cron job. so that i can schedule it at 15 min interval and in every 15 min script run-check-email new file-exit.
Please suggest...

Comment: Why not just change the sleep intveral to 15 minutes? `sleep 900`

Comment: changing the sleep time will not quit the process it will be on running. i want run-check-email new files-exit program this cycle in every 15 min. Reason of doing this is decreasing resource consumption

Comment: Given that you're on linux, you can check `inotifywait` from `inotify-tools`, which is exactly for this purpose. There's no need for periodical checks - when the new file comes in it'll notify, else just waits there.

Comment: i cannot use inotify. only cron and script are the options

Comment: @Readerlook, is this homework? Why do you have the tool limitations?

Comment: :) the server space i purchased for my application is not having such tool and they do not allow me to install.

Comment: MOST OF THE PORBLEM IS SOLVED

Comment: need one more help, by using '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n'  i am getting whole path with filename. i just want one or two last directory and filename. can any one suggest me how i can achieve this

Comment: @Readerlook, There is basically no resource consumption while you're in the call `sleep 900`

Comment: thank you @cmh , all these scripts are giving file creation time result of find or ls -lrt command, i was looking for file arrival time

Answer (score 0):

Your cron should be...

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/your/script
```

And your script...

```
if [ ! -f /tmp/filemonitor.lck ]; then

  touch /tmp/filemonitor.lck
  monitor_dir=/path/to/dir
  email=me@gmail.com

  if [ ! -f /tmp/oldmonitor.txt ];then touch /tmp/oldmonitor.txt; fi;

  find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort > /tmp/actual_monitor.txt

  added=$(comm -13 /tmp/oldmonitor.txt /tmp/actual_monitor.txt)
  echo $added

  [ "$added" != "" ] &&
  find $added -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' |
  mail -s "incoming" "$email"

  rm -f /tmp/oldmonitor.txt

  mv /tmp/actual_monitor.txt /tmp/oldmonitor.txt

  rm -f /tmp/filemonitor.lck

fi;
```

Had to change vars for files, but tested and working!!!

Comment: it will need some tweaking, because as is, each invokation goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: But now it will only catch new files created between the two invocations of `find`. If it's run like this from a cron, it will need to store state somewhere, probably a file. (Alternatively use the -mtime command on find).

Comment: exactly cmh, this is the problem. without cron script is perfect but if we want to run this in cron then we need to look into some other solution. because once script is exit then there will be no previous values in variables.

Comment: ./imp.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./imp.sh: line 9: `  if[ ! -f /tmp/oldmonitor.txt ]; then touch /tmp/oldmonitor.txt; fi;'

Comment: giving error at line 7 in above code (then touch /tmp/oldmonitor.txt; fi;) error is syntax error near unexpected token `then touch /tmp/oldmonitor.txt; fi;'

Comment: Which result you expect besides file data on mail?

Comment: need one more help, by using '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n'  i am getting whole path with filename. i just want one or two last directory and filename. can any one suggest me how i can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

you should use `inotifywait`

more info and man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

use this:

```
monitor_dir=/tmp/1123
while true
do
    d=$(inotifywait -e  create $monitor_dir --format "%f" 2>/dev/null)
    if [[ -f $d ]]
    then
        #echo "filename is: " $monitor_dir/$d
        find $monitor_dir/$d  -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n'
    fi
done
```

Comment: in above answer i am getting everything. need one more help, by using '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n'  i am getting whole path with filename. i just want one or two last directory and filename. can any one suggest me how i can achieve this

Comment: do you know how to do it